# Можно ли использовать глагол "существовать" в настоящем времени в этом предложении?

Tags: согласование, глаголы

Пример:
"Вопрос существует не только в наше время: он был актуален и в прошлом."
Применимо ли здесь "существует" в этом времени? Нет ли здесь нарушения "согласования времени", как будто вопрос одновременно существует и сейчас, и в прошлом?
Спасибо!

Comment: А что тут смущает? Может быть "не только"? Что по-вашему такое "не только" или "только"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы правы, есть такая проблема. Получается так, что он существует не только в наше время, а и в какое-то другое время. Да и глагол "существует" здесь не подходит.

Вариант правки:
*Вопрос не из новых, он был актуален и в прошлом.*

Если звучание вас не волнует, а надо просто поправить структуру, то решение — переставить "не только" вперёд (тогда оно будет указывать не какое-то другое время, а на какое-то другое действие):
*Вопрос не только существует в наше время, он был актуален и в прошлом.

Вопрос не только существует в наше время, он существовал и в прошлом.*

По поводу двоеточия:
Лучше без него. С одной стороны, раскрывается содержание, но этого раскрытия мало: сообщается о коротком факте, который, в принципе, ожидаем. Для двоеточия раскрытие должно быть более объёмным и неочевидным.